# Dúvida sobre consulta sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select, tsql

Estou com uma dúvida. Acredito não ser nada complexo, porém não consegui resolver.

Por exemplo, tenho esta consulta:

```
select * from Paciente where ClinicaID = 3
```

O seu resultado seria estes 3 registros:

```
NomePaciente  HoraAtendimento   Ativo  ClinicaID
Teste2          9:30:00         FALSE   3
Teste3           9:00:00        TRUE    3
Teste4          9:00:00         TRUE    3
```

Preciso de uma consulta que me retorne as linhas para o meu sistema somente se todos as linhas forem Ativo = true, portanto se tiver alguma linha false,
não me retornará nenhuma linha.

Sendo assim: Se todas as linhas forem true na minha consulta, retorná todas as linhas. Se tiver algum false, não deverá retornar nenhuma.

Comment: A resposta do Evandro é simples e o mais precisa possivel, o filtro pelo campo ativo retorna apenas as que você deseja.

Comment: @ThiagoOliveira, simples porém errada. Olhe a resposta do @JoséDiz, ela está plenamente correta e também mostra graficamente que ela está correta. Se por acaso a clínica tiver um paciente com `ativo = 'FALSE'`, então não exibe nenhuma linha. Caso contrário, caso todas as linhas estejam marcadas com `ativo = 'TRUE'`, então retorna todas as linhas

Answer (score 5):

> *Se todas as linhas forem true na minha consulta, retorná todas as*
>   *linhas. Se tiver algum false, não deverá retornar nenhuma.*

Há algumas formas. Eis uma que utiliza a função EXISTS.

```
-- código #1
SELECT P.NomePaciente, P.HoraAtendimento, P.ClinicaID, P.Ativo
  from Paciente as P
  where P.ClinicaID = 3
        and P.Ativo = 'TRUE'
        and not exists (SELECT * 
                          from Paciente as P2
                          where P2.ClinicaID = P.ClinicaID
                                and P2.Ativo = 'FALSE');
```

---

**Demonstração de funcionamento do código, por Leo Caracciolo**

> *Se todas as linhas forem true na minha consulta, retorná todas as*
>   linhas. [image: true]
>
> *Se tiver algum false,*

[image: paciente]

> *não deverá retornar nenhuma.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo: Grato por acrescentar as ilustrações com a demonstração de funcionamento do código proposto.

Comment: A conversação foi transferida para o chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69429/discussion-between-jose-diz-and-jefferson-quesado

Answer (score 3):

Derivando da ideia do @JoséDiz, você poderia fazer uma junção à esquerda da tabela com ela mesma, pondo na cláusula da junção o mesmo identificador de clínica e `T2` estar com `T2.ativo = 'FALSE'`. Feita essa junção, se existir algum dado de `T2` sendo retornado em alguma de suas colunas, então não devo imprimir essa linha. A vantagem desse método é que, se aparece em uma linha, então deve aparecer em TODAS as linhas da mesma clínica. Logo, só verificar pela nulidade de `T2.clinicaId` no `WHERE` é o suficiente para imprimir todas as linhas ou nenhuma linha.

Sobre performance, eu tenho minhas dúvidas. Eu sempre *acho* que subqueries atrapalham (essa generalização é ruim). Agora, sobre leitura, com certeza a do @JoséDiz é mais fácil de ler.

```
SELECT T1.NomePaciente, T1.HoraAtendimento, T1.ClinicaID, T1.Ativo
  from Paciente as T1 left join
    Paciente as T2 on (T1.clinicaId = T2.clinicaId AND T2.ativo = 'FALSE')
  where T1.ClinicaID = 3
        and T1.Ativo = 'TRUE'
        and T2.clinicaId IS NULL
```

Comment: Jefferson, falta adicionar uma condição na cláusula WHERE, para excluir os pacientes que têm pelo menos um registo com Ativo = FALSE.

Comment: @bruno, o bom foi que eu disse no texto que ia fazer a verificação e não fiz! Obrigado pelo olho atento

Answer (score -1):

É só adicionar mais um filtro:

```
SELECT * FROM Paciente WHERE ClinicaID = 3 AND Ativo = TRUE
```

Comment: Mas não resolve a questão, porque vai me retornar a linha que tem o valor false.

Comment: não, se você fizer como descrito ai, retornada apenas as verdadeiras.

Comment: isso vai retornar as que tem ativo = true, ele diz `se tiver alguma linha false, não me retornará nenhuma linha.`

Comment: Tive de negativar essa resposta pelos motivos apresentados pelo @LeoCaracciolo e pelo Ralfe. Você não se atentou que, se tiver pelo menos um paciente na clínica que esteja com `ATIVO = 'FALSE'`, nenhuma linha deve ser retornada

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado meus parabéns! não podemos errar na resposta que somos punidos. É uma "competição" ou um forum de ajuda!?

Comment: Estou usando [guia de uso do downvote](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4703/64969) para respostas conforme discutido no meta.